# Image segmentation and its performance comparison in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, image-segmentation

Hi,

I am working on Image segmentation based on ROI and Contour algorithm. 
I wish to compare the performance of these two methods.

1. On what basis I can compare this two methods and prove that one is better than the other?
2. Please help me with matlab code to do so. I have the code which gives segmented images for both the methods but I don't know how to compare these methods. Please help me with MATLAB Code. If required, I will provide the code which gives the segmented images for both these methods.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing image segmentation algorithms is a very complicated task. Because it is not always clear what are the "true" segments of an image.
However, there are several academic benchmarks for this end (if you agree with their proposed segmentation measure).

The most prominent benchmark is:
[BSDS](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/)

Another is:
[Alpert's segmentation evaluation dataset](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/Seg_Evaluation_DB/index.html)

I believe both has Matlab interface.